# How to get total count of two tables using stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
  I need to create a stored procedure for getting the count of two table by using where clause condition, but when i try to create procedure it shows error

Query : CREATE PROCEDURE bcp.getTotalCount BEGIN   -- Create two integer values  DECLARE @tableOneCount int, @tableTwoCount int  -- Get ...
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
  -- Create two integer values
    DECLARE @tableOneCount int, @tableTwoCount' at line 2
```

This is the stored procedure i tried to create

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS bcp.getTotalCount $$
CREATE PROCEDURE bcp.getTotalCount
BEGIN
  -- Create two integer values
    DECLARE @tableOneCount INT, @tableTwoCount INT

    -- Get the number of rows from the first table
    SELECT @tableOneCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM candidates WHERE active=1)
    SELECT @tableTwoCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM voters_enrollment WHERE active=1)

    -- Return the sum of the two table sizes
    SELECT TotalCount = @tableOneCount + @tableTwoCount
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

For better understanding i tried with simple sql query like this

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM candidates WHERE active=1)+ 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM voters_enrollment WHERE active=1) AS Total
```

I get the result as

```
Total
10
```

Like this way i need to create the procedure and call it to get the same result by using simple sql query. can anyone help me to solve this please.

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE bcp.getTotalCount()` missing the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put AS after the create statement.

```
    DELIMITER $$

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS bcp.getTotalCount $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE bcp.getTotalCount

    AS

    BEGIN

  -- Create two integer values
    DECLARE @tableOneCount INT, @tableTwoCount INT

    -- Get the number of rows from the first table
    SELECT @tableOneCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM candidates WHERE active=1)
    SELECT @tableTwoCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM voters_enrollment WHERE active=1)

    -- Return the sum of the two table sizes
    SELECT TotalCount = @tableOneCount + @tableTwoCount
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, mate:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS bcp_getTotalCount $$
CREATE PROCEDURE bcp_getTotalCount()
BEGIN
    -- clear/initialize session variables
    SET
        @tableOneCount = 0,
        @tableTwoCount = 0;
    START TRANSACTION;
    -- get record count from the source tables
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @tableOneCount FROM candidates WHERE active = 1;
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @tableOneCount FROM voters_enrollment WHERE active = 1;
    -- return the sum of the two table sizes
        SELECT TotalCount = @tableOneCount + @tableTwoCount;
    COMMIT;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

*MySQL Transaction for Atomicity*